# False Positive Matching Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

[image: Matching]

Hi there I am having trouble with matching because it is showing me false positive match because everytime i enter for example another 14.33 it keeps saying match. What i need help with is find the numbers that are not in A and the ones that are not in B. Like in A column i have 11, 12 , 13, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16 and In B column i have 11,12,12,13,13,14,14,15. I need it to identify in those columns which ones are missing from the other because in A we have 3 13's and one is missing and 16 which are missing in column B , while in column B there are 2 12's and one is missing in A and 2 14's which one is missing in A . I hope i made some sense.

This is the code im currently using `=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No Match in B", "Match in B")`

What I'm doing it for is for balancing my receipts what I see in the bank account and what i have in paper and find the missing ones. Thank you

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1490352/edit) to include the formula you are using?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad sorry I was still editing it . I have included the formula . This is the formula `=IF(COUNTIF($B:$B, $A2)=0, "No Match in B", "Match in B")`

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the count in one column to that point against the total count in the other column:

```
COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2)
```

So for column A:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2),"Match in B","No Match in B")
```

For Column B:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)<=COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2),"Match in A","No Match in A")
```

[image]

---

To deal with the Blanks us an outer IF:

```
 =IF($A2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)<=COUNTIF($B:$B,$A2),"Match in B","No Match in B"),"")
```

and

```
 =IF($B2<>"",IF(COUNTIF($B$2:$B2,$B2)<=COUNTIF($A:$A,$B2),"Match in A","No Match in A"),"")
```

Comment: So when I did that on real example I saw this happen [link](https://i.imgur.com/dLHZrRT.png)

Comment: It seems that its matching itself in the same column as well as 12.56 in column A was posted 3 times while in B it posted 2 times but it still said matching for the 3rd 12.56 in A while not actually matching anything

Comment: Did you adjust the row number to match where you put the first formula? it seems to be a row off.

Comment: @Kataka see edit.  It now starts in row 2.

Comment: So i did the repair you did . So its saying Match in A for 1.75 even though there is nothing to match [link](https://i.imgur.com/Dnpj6j8.png)

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this Scott I really do , you dont understand how much I appreciate it

Comment: Oh wait I think its matching empty spaces as numbers that why it says matching

Comment: @Kataka no it is saying there is a match in A for the blank cell in B.  1.75 is not matching in B

Comment: Is there anything i can place for it to not count the empty spaces just wondering or do i just keep it like that ?

Comment: @Kataka see edit

Comment: I'll try it and tell you once i do try it . Omg you are a life saver

Comment: It’s now saying for everything #name?